# Solr: change order of documents if both have same value

Tags: php, solr, lucene

Is it possible to make such a modification for SOLR results that will change the order of document if particular value is equal to value in previous documents ? Eg split products from same shop.

Currently im doing this directly in PHP but I can only change the order of documents on one particaluar page but then at the end of that page I have two lines with documents with same shop_id next to each other.

[Sorting in PHP](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/72f18b4022b01f48e62f85045f3eef702f1731ee)

Is it possible to achieve similiar thing directly in SOLR? Ideal solution is that product with same shop_id will be separated by other product(s) with different shop_id - I aware that it could affect SOLR score.

Mockups:

[Current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WL8nz.png)

[After applying modifications in PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kp869.png)

[Ideal solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5dA1.png)

Comment: could you please explain ideal solution? i'm not getting how this shop splitting is working

Comment: Ok, so now products are displayed like this: prod1_from_shop1, prod2_from_shop1, prod1_from_shop2, (...)

What I want to achieve is: prod1_from_shop1, prod1_from_shop2, prod1_from_shop3, prod2_from_shop1, prod2_from_shop2, (...)

I want to avoid situation, where products from same shop are displayed next to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As most of the use cases similar to this - it’s not recommended to apply thos changes in Solr directly, since by design Solr is very abstract from those requirements. All needed manipulations **should happen** on the **client** side or **API** level.

While, I must admit, you could do anything in Solr, most likely this will require writing custom Solr component, which would **complicate** your deployment process quite a lot with a little benefit.

Regarding single page problem, you could try to request bigger page size, e.g. 20 but show only first N to the user, and then applying your rendering logic as you want

Comment: well I thought that this is doable :( thanks for clarifying